# Retain the user defined sort order in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, sorting, wpfdatagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid that is populated with data from DataSet. I have `CanUserSortColumns` set to **true**.

Is it possible to retain the sorting that the user specified when the grid is refreshed? I have it retaining the item that was selected using

```
  object selectedItem = dgInvoiceHeads.SelectedItem;
```

before the refresh takes place and then placing

```
 dgInvoiceHeads.SelectedItem = selectedItem;
```

after the refresh takes place.

But I can't seem to get it to retain the specified sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of my colleagues came up with this. It seems to be working correctly. The only thing is I think the column headers need to be the same in the DataGrid as they are in the DB.

```
string sortHeader;
string prevSortHeader;
SortDescription sd;

private void dgInvoiceHeads_Sorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e) {
  sortHeader = e.Column.Header.ToString();

  if (sortHeader == prevSortHeader) {
    sd = new SortDescription(sortHeader, ListSortDirection.Descending);
  }
  else {
    sd = new SortDescription(sortHeader, ListSortDirection.Ascending);
  }
  prevSortHeader = sortHeader;
}
```

HTH

Comment: You can get around the problem of having to have your headers the same as your class members by using the SortMemberPath in the column instance rather than the Header property.  `sortHeader = e.Column.SortMemberPath`

Comment: `sd` is not utilized in the above code sample. So how does it work?

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried getting the collectionview for the dataset?

```
CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(yourDataSet).SortDescriptions
```

This will give you an array of the current sortdescriptions.  You can then persist these, and the next time round apply them as follows

```
CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(yourDataSet).SortDescriptions.Add(...)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yep ! this should be the right solution.. and the only one. And if i'm correct, you don't even have to "remember" previous sorting or grouping : once they are declared int your collectionViewSource, all new added items will be sorted accordingly, as if you just do a brut force  '.Refresh()' on the 'ICollectionView' Object...

Answer (score 4):

The following code was pulled from this [forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/1acf9dbd-d56b-474d-8e14-f35f848af410/) and it shows how to obtain the sort descriptions and column information and restore it.

```
List<DataGridColumn> GetColumnInfo(DataGrid dg) {
    List<DataGridColumn> columnInfos = new List<DataGridColumn>();
    foreach (var column in dg.Columns) {
        columnInfos.Add(column);
    }
    return columnInfos;
}

List<SortDescription> GetSortInfo(DataGrid dg) {
    List<SortDescription> sortInfos = new List<SortDescription>();
    foreach (var sortDescription in dg.Items.SortDescriptions) {
        sortInfos.Add(sortDescription);
    }
    return sortInfos;
}

void SetColumnInfo(DataGrid dg, List<DataGridColumn> columnInfos) {
    columnInfos.Sort((c1, c2) => { return c1.DisplayIndex - c2.DisplayIndex; });
    foreach (var columnInfo in columnInfos) {
        var column = dg.Columns.FirstOrDefault(col => col.Header == columnInfo.Header);
        if (column != null) {
            column.SortDirection = columnInfo.SortDirection;
            column.DisplayIndex = columnInfo.DisplayIndex;
            column.Visibility = columnInfo.Visibility;
        }
    }
}

void SetSortInfo(DataGrid dg, List<SortDescription> sortInfos) {
    dg.Items.SortDescriptions.Clear();
    foreach (var sortInfo in sortInfos) {
        dg.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(sortInfo);
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this is ancient, but just wanted to point out that in this example, the DataGridColumns are stored by reference, meaning that any changes made by a refresh of the DataSource, wil also update the 'stored' DataGridColumn.
Instead data from DataGridColumn should be cloned.

Answer (score 1):

```
 private void testGrid_Sorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
        {

 ListSortDirection direction = (e.Column.SortDirection != ListSortDirection.Ascending) ?
                                ListSortDirection.Ascending : ListSortDirection.Descending;

// You will get the current direction in direction

        }

This is another solution
```